# Can I compute signal-to-noise ratio on a vector-valued or multi-channel signal?

Tags: snr, multi-channel, emg

I have a dataset that contains multiple channels recorded over time (think EEG or EMG), and I'm working on a computational model for this data. When I have a working version of the model, I'd like to compare the model's predictions to some held-out test recordings. I thought it would be nice use some sort of signal-to-noise analysis to do this comparison, but I can't find much help on whether it even makes sense to try to compute SnR for multi-channel data.

Everything I've seen so far about computing SnR assumes that you have a single time-varying channel to analyze. Should I compute the SnR for each channel of my data independently, and then average the values across channels? How is this sort of analysis typically handled in signal processing?

Comment: Considering your approach a "Goodness of fit" or norm or information content metric might be useful metric.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the way SNR is calculated in RGB images as a starting point.

In RGB images, the image SNR is calculated using the familiar formula

$$
\frac{\mu}{\sigma}
$$

Where $\mu$ is the "whole image" mean and $\sigma$ is the "whole image" standard deviation. To calculate these "whole image" values, each of the RGB channels is first converted to the common currency of *luminosity* by one of several formulas, generally weighted sums:
$$
L = W_{R}\mu_{R} + W_{G}\mu_{G} + W_{B}\mu_{G}
$$

Where $\mu$ are means and $W$ are respective weights for the R, G, and B channels of the image (in the Adobe formula, for example, weights are 0.2974, 0.6273, and 0.0753 respectively), and L is luminosity.

For whole image standard deviation, the variance includes the covariances of the channels, so the full formula is
$$
Var(L) = \sum_{i,j} (r_{i,j}^2Var_{R} + g_{i,j}^2Var_{G} + ...
$$
$$
b_{i,j}^2Var_{B}+ 2r_{i,j}g_{i,j}Cov_{R, G} + ...
$$
$$
2r_{i,j}b_{i,j}Cov_{R, B} + 2g_{i,j}b_{i,j}Cov_{G, B} )
$$
where $i$ and $j$ are pixel indices, which is a more expensive calculation and not as commonly used in industry. [Oscar de Lama](http://www.odelama.com/data-analysis/How-to-Compute-RGB-Image-Standard-Deviation-from-Channels-Statistics/) reports that the Adobe formula simply disregards the covariances:
$$
W_{R}^2Var_{R} + W_{G}^2Var_{G} + W_{B}^2Var_{B}
$$
and suggests a compromise formula:
$$
W_{R}Var_{R} + W_{G}Var_{G} + W_{B}Var_{B} ...
$$
$$
+ (2/3)(W_{R}\mu_{R}^2 + W_{G}\mu_{G}^2 + W_{B}\mu_{B}^2) ...
$$
$$
- (2/3)⋅(\hat{W}_{RG}⋅\mu{R}⋅\mu{G} + \hat{W}_{RG}⋅\mu{R}⋅\mu{B} + \hat{W}_{RB}⋅\mu{G}⋅\mu{B})
$$
Where $W$ are the earlier weights, and $\hat{W}(X,Y) = \sqrt{XY} / K$ where $K$ normalizes $\hat{W}$ such that $\sum \hat{W} = 1$.

If the vector-valued image weights all components equally, then W reduces to 1, simplifying the formulas.